# $\operatorname{span}\{x_1,\ldots,x_n\} = \mathbb{C}^n$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

If $A$ is a $n \times n$ Hermitian matrix, then is it right that,
\begin{equation}
\operatorname{span}\{x_1,\ldots,x_n\} = \mathbb{C}^n \text{?}
\end{equation}
where $x_i \ne 0$ is the eigenvector associated with the eigenvalue $\lambda_i$ of $A$. That is, $A x_i = \lambda_i x_i, i=1,\ldots,n$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is correct (as long as the span is taken over $\mathbb C$ and $\{x_1,...,x_n \}$ is linearly independent). Hermitian matrices are always diagonalizable, which is equivalent to the statement that the eigenvectors form a basis for the vector space. For a proof of this look at the Spectral theorem, which not only tells us that there is a basis consisting of eigenvectors of $A$ but also that there is an orthogonal basis consisting of eigenvectors of $A$.

Comment: Small nit-pick: It's not guaranteed to be orthogonal if an eigenvalue has multiplicity${}>1$. You can still choose an ortogonal basis, but it doesn't happen automatically the way it does for distinct eigenvalues.

Comment: So in other words, if I want to find out an orthonormal basis out of the eigenvectors of $A$, the only calculation I need to do is dividing each eigenvector by it length. Am I right?

Comment: @winston You must also keep Arthur's comment in mind. You must first make sure that the $n$ eigenvectors are linearly independent. Eigenvectors for unique eigenvalues are necessarily independent but for eigenvalues of multiplicity $k>1$ you must choose $k$ eigenvectors that are linearly independent of one another. This means that if $A$ has $n$ unique eigenvalues the eigenvectors will necessarily be orthogonal. If not you can pick any $n$ linearly independent eigenvectors and perform the Gram-Schmidt algorithm on this set to get an orthonormal basis of eigenvectors of $A$.

Comment: @winston So if the basis is already orthogonal (either the eigenvalues are distinct or you already picked  the orthogonal one) then all that you need to do is divide by the length of each vector to normalize. While there exists an orthonormal basis of eigenvectors of $A$ there may also exist bases of eigenvectors that are not orthogonal, in which case you can just use the Gram-Schmidt algorithm to get the orthogonal one.

Comment: For example, the identity matrix is Hermitian and diagonalisable, with an basis of eigenvalues $(1, 0), (1, 1)$. It's not orthogonal, but you can easily use Gram-Schmidt to make it orthonormal. The Spectral Theorem guarantees you may always find an orthonormal basis of eigenvectors for Hermitian matrices.

Comment: @winston This is correct, and the reason is because the Gram-Schmidt algorithm preserves the span of the original set. By this I mean that if $\{ y_1,...,y_n \}$ is obtained by Gram-Schmidt on $\{ x_1,...,x_n \}$ then $\text{span} \{ y_1,...,y_k \} =\text{span} \{ x_1,...,x_k \}$ for all $k=1,2,...,n$.

Answer (score 2):

A matrix is diagonalisable if and only if the generalised eigenspaces all equal the (non-generalised) eigenspaces, as the generalised eigenspaces contain the eigenspaces, but direct sum to the entire space. This is therefore equivalent to showing $\mathrm{ker} (M - \lambda I) =\mathrm{ker} (M - \lambda I)^2$ for all eigenvalues $\lambda$. Note that $\mathrm{ker} (M - \lambda I) \subseteq \mathrm{ker} (M - \lambda I)^2$ is always true.

Suppose $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue for $A$, the Hermitian matrix. Then $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$ (a nice exercise, if you're not familiar). Suppose $v \in \mathrm{ker} (M - \lambda I)^2$. Then,
$$0 = v^*(M - \lambda I)^2v = (v^*(M^* - \overline{\lambda} I^*)) (M - \lambda I)v = ((M - \lambda I)v)^* (M - \lambda I)v = \|(M - \lambda I)v\|^2$$

Hence $v \in \mathrm{ker} (M - \lambda I)$, so we get $\mathrm{ker} (M - \lambda I) = \mathrm{ker} (M - \lambda I)^2$, and so $M$ is diagonalisable.